# compile translation files when calling setup.py install

Tags: python, setuptools, python-babel

I'm developing a Flask application using Babel. Thanks to [Distutils/Setuptools Integration](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/setup.html), all the parameters of compile/extract/... functions are stored in `setup.cfg` and compiling the i18n files is as easy as

```
./setup.py compile_catalog
```

Great. Now I would like this to be done automatically when running

```
./setup.py install
```

In `make`'s words, that would be letting `install` target depend on `compile_catalog` target.

#### The context

We store only translation (`.po`) files in the code repository. [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) excludes `.mo` and `.pot` files from being tracked.

When a developer pulls a new revision of the code, he runs

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to update dependencies and install the project in development mode. Then, using above command line, he compiles the translation binary (`.mo`) files.

Is there a simple and recommended way to modify `setup.py` to do both operations in one step? Or am I trying to misuse `setuptools`?

Using a script that like this would work for development purposes:

```
#!/bin/sh
./setup.py compile_catalog
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but I would like a solution that also works when the package is installed with usual `setup.py` install instructions, like if installed from PyPi.

Should I understand that `setuptools` are not meant to be used like this, and people distributing software compile their translation files either manually or using custom scripts when creating their archives, rather than relying on `setup.py` to compile them at installation time?

I didn't find many posts on the Internet addressing this. The ones I found involved running `pybabel` command line interface from a function in `setup.py`, which sounds like a shame as it misses the point of setuptools integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your demand is totally valid and I'm quite surprised that there seems to be no official guideline on how to accomplish this.

The project I working on now also went multilingual and this is what I did:

- In `setup.cfg`, make appropriate entries so that `compile_catalog` can be run without options.
- In `setup.py`, subclass the install command from `setuptools`:

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

class InstallWithCompile(install):
    def run(self):
        from babel.messages.frontend import compile_catalog
        compiler = compile_catalog(self.distribution)
        option_dict = self.distribution.get_option_dict('compile_catalog')
        compiler.domain = [option_dict['domain'][1]]
        compiler.directory = option_dict['directory'][1]
        compiler.run()
        super().run()
```

Then, when calling setup(), register our InstallWithCompile command with the name "install" and make sure that the *.mo files will be included in the package:

```
setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={
        'install': InstallWithCompile,
    },
    ...
    package_data={'': ['locale/*/*/*.mo', 'locale/*/*/*.po']},
)
```

Since babel is used during the setup, you should add it as a setup dependency:

```
setup_requires=[
    'babel',
],
```

Note that a package (here, babel) appearing in both `setup_requires` and `install_requires` won't be installed correctly using `python setup.py install` due to an [issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/391) in `setuptools`, but it works fine with `pip install`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late feedback. I applied your solution and it works fine. I edited your answer to add a few informations.